# Can't access port 8080, 50000 and 8888 while installing jenkins and jupyter

Tags: docker, jenkins, jupyter-notebook, dockerfile, port

I am new to dokers. I need jenkins and jupyter notebook in the same container. I have written the following Dockerfile but I can't access localhost:**8888 or 8080 or 50000** when I run this image. However, these ports work very well when I run the **official** jenkins image. So, I don't know where I am making the mistake in **my Dockerfile**.

```
# using ubuntu as base image
FROM ubuntu:20.04
# installing python version 3.8
RUN apt-get update -y \
&& apt-get install -y apt-utils \
&& apt-get install python3.8 -y

# installing jupyter notebook
RUN apt-get install jupyter -y
EXPOSE 8888

# installing jenkins
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get install dialog apt-utils -y
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gnupg2
RUN apt-get install -y wget
RUN wget -q -O - https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/jenkins.io.key | apt-key add -
RUN sh -c 'echo deb https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ > \
 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jenkins.list'
RUN apt-get update 
RUN apt-get install jenkins -y
EXPOSE 50000 8080

# removing unnecessary files
RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
COPY sample.py .
LABEL maintainer=Ammar

CMD ["bash"]
```

Comment: Did you make sure your container is actually running? It probably exits right after starting. What's the docker command you're using to create and start the container?

Comment: Check with `docker ps` if container is up and check as well log `docker logs CONTAINER_NAME/ID `

Comment: I used the following to command to start the container:
docker run -td --name container32 -p 8080:8080 image32

Comment: yes, the container is running. This is what I get under ports when I use docker ps command:
8888/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, 50000/tcp   c321

Comment: when I run : docker port container32, I get : 8080/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:8080

Comment: but still nothing shows in my browser at localhost:8080